# How to get a value of HTML drop down menu using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML script that has a dropdown menu with some options. Once you have selected your topic it goes to my PHP script called `process.php`. In that `process.php` it takes the value of the HTML dropdown menu and writes it to a file. Or at least that is what I want it to do...

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" action="process.php" name="form1" method="post"
     <select id="form">
         <option name="--Select_a_Topic--" value="--Select a Topic--">--Select a Topic--</option>
      <option name="Dog" value="Dog">Dog</option>
      <option name="Cat" value="Cat">Cat</option>
      <option name="Other" value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

help.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form')){
    $topic = $_POST['form'];
    }
$fh = fopen('putithere.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fh, $topic);
fclose('putithere.txt');
?>
```

PHP error log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: form in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/process.php on line 'whatever'
```

Comment: your select needs a **name**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
<form id="form1" action="help.php" name="form1" method="post">
         <select name="pet" id="form">
          <option value="-1">--Select a Topic--</option>
          <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

now option that you selected is accessible with `$_POST['pet']` in php.
also it's a good idea that set your default value to `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Give your select tag a "name" attribute.

```
<select name='form' id='form'>
```

You should also give your options the same "name" as the select.

Answer (score 0):

You have `process.php` in your question and the form action is `help.php`?

Also, try creating a file you know you have permission to write to, and then attempt to write to that file.

Comment: My mistake. I'm sorry. It is supposed to be process.php I saw it somewhere and just put it in by accident

Comment: The other two answers identified that you are missing a `name=` attribute on your select element.  That is most likely the error.